# iPhone app won't run on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I've encountered problem when running iPhone only apps to iPad. The error from crash log is

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00ac3ff8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38cccdd4 allocate_pages + 352
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38cccace large_malloc + 70
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38cc83ee szone_malloc_should_clear + 1362
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38cc7e68 malloc_zone_malloc + 88
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2aa24ea2 __CFStringChangeSizeMultiple + 866
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2a983554 CFStringCreateMutableCopy + 408
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2a99abba -[__NSCFString mutableCopyWithZone:] + 22
7   MyApp                       0x006a274c 0xa3000 + 6289228
8   MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
9   MyApp                       0x006a2800 0xa3000 + 6289408
10  MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
11  MyApp                       0x006a2800 0xa3000 + 6289408
12  MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
13  MyApp                       0x006a2800 0xa3000 + 6289408
14  MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
15  MyApp                       0x006a2800 0xa3000 + 6289408
16  MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
17  MyApp                       0x006a2800 0xa3000 + 6289408
18  MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
19  MyApp                       0x006a2800 0xa3000 + 6289408
20  MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
21  MyApp                       0x006a2800 0xa3000 + 6289408
22  MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
23  MyApp                       0x006a2800 0xa3000 + 6289408
24  MyApp                       0x006a2a7e 0xa3000 + 6290046
```

In the XCode, the crashed cause by '[UIImage imageNamed]'. Which confused me. I wonder how to debug and fix this kind of error

UPDATE :

the breakpoint stop at this line of code

```
- (UIButton *)customBackButton
{
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"actionbar_back_nor.png"];
    UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"actionbar_back_pre.png"];
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setImage:buttonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,44,44);
    UIEdgeInsets insets;
    if (IOS_VERSION_7_OR_BETTER) {
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(11, 0, 11, 22);
    }else{
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(11, 11, 11, 11);
    }

    aButton.imageEdgeInsets = insets;

    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

I changed the '[UIImage imageNamed:]' to '[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]' and the things run normal. Why the '[UIImage imageNamed:]' cause this error?

Comment: If you get this error then your app compiles. Is your image in the list of files to be copied?

Comment: yes, i have no problem installed it on iPhone either 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: you should update the title

Comment: @Suprie please post here a bit of code arround `[UIImage imageNamed]`.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev It seems that every '[UIImage imageNamed]' is crashing. if i change it to '[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile]' it runs normally.

Comment: @Suprie at least you have to use `[UIImage imageNamed:]` instead of `[UIImage imageNamed]`. So please just post your code.

Comment: is you image file present in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources ?

Comment: @Niko yes, my image is present in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you send the message to `UIImage` (call static function) with invalid parameter. For sure.

That's why you are getting error on `-[__NSCFString mutableCopyWithZone:]`, because `[UIImage imageNamed:]` expects `NSString` parameter, but gets something wrong.

So please post your code.

**Update**

Since you've said that you compiled your app for iPhone only and run it on iPad, I think the problem is in image lookup on iPad. Unfortunately I can't go deeper, but according to this document https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html we know that iPad looks up for iPad-specific resources first. So I'm not sure, but it seems like `[UIImage imageNamed:]` confuses somewhere at this point. You can try to copy your `actionbar_back_nor.png` and `actionbar_back_pre.png` to `actionbar_back_nor~ipad.png` and `actionbar_back_pre~ipad.png`.

I am not sure, but this seems like the only point where reason can be hidden.

But problem is very interesting and I'll research it for myself in a few days. So if you will need more information, we can be in touch.

Comment: i've update my question. Including the snippet of the imageNamed

Comment: @Suprie okay, the problem is very strange. I will try to figure it out a bit later.

Comment: thank you very much sir for your time. I also found this problem strange, although i believed this caused by wrong build settings. If i change to universal build, it worked like a charm. Failed if trying to install iPhone only apps to iPad.

Comment: @Suprie on which line your app crashes? On this `UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"actionbar_back_nor.png"];`?

Comment: yes, on that line. If i removed that line of code, that it will move to other `[UIImage imageNamed:]`;

Comment: thank you sir, i'll try to rename the image to actionbar_back_nor~ipad.png and tell the result. But as far as i know, if you ran iPhone only apps on iPad, it will used the iPhone only resources.

Answer (score 0):

Just add exception breakpoint and it will show you exactly where your code is crashing, and then use the mighty debugger.

Comment: Using exception breakpoint and debugger, only shows __lldb_unnamed_function1296$$MyApp

Comment: And what your are seeing in a stacktrace?

Comment: the breakpoint pointed to '[UIImage imageNamed:]'. I've updated the question with the snippet of code that breakpoint pointed me.

Comment: Yes, all image is included in target.

Comment: This isn't an answer it is a comment.